# UI Automation store screenshot in given path

Tags: ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I can see screenshot in log, but I can't store it in given path. How can I store it in given path, e.g.: `\users\downloads\test.png`

Screenshot is taken using the code below:

```
target.captureScreenWithName( "screenshot1.png" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Instruments** window, in the **left sidebar**, there is the **Logging** section on the very bottom. You can save all your log results (logs, screenshots etc.) in desired folder by pressing **Export Traced Results…** button.

Also, you can check **Continuously Log Results** checkmark and specify required folder. All log results will be saved in that folder automatically.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to do it by script to save only required image to the destination folder? Such that i can save photos to the different folders.

Comment: When using command line tools (instruments, rather than Instruments), I cannot find the screenshot file in trace document. However, when I open the trace document by Instrument, I can see the screenshot in 'Extended Detail' panel. Now I wonder where is this screenshot exactly located in trace document (actually it's a folder)?